# how to transfer data from one html page to another using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to transfer data from one html page to another page, so I wrote this program:

page1.ejs:

```
<a href="/events" onclick="send()">
  <span  class="message">
    new alert
  </span>
</a>

function send() {
  $mesg = $('.message');
  var msg = $mesg.text();
  var msg1 = msg.replace(/\s/g, '');
  localStorage.setItem("message", msg1);
}
```

page2.ejs:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("message");
</script>
<td id="event"></td>
```

But I don't get the data transferred from the pages? what is my mistake?

Comment: Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data. make sure both pages are from the same origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in *page2.ejs*:

**Problem:** The HTMLElement `<td id="event"></td>` is not yet available when your `<script>` block is parsed and executed, so `document.getElementById("event")` returns undefined.

**Solution:** Move the `<script>` block to the bottom, beneath `<td id="event"></td>` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    page1.ejs:

    On click of submit -
       window.location.href="page2.ejs.html?text1="+$('#text1').val()

    page2.ejs:

    $(document).ready(function(){
     var value1 = document.URL.indexOf('?text1=');//value from pag1.ejs

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define the Send() function inside script tag
and Page 2 run the java script when page ready

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 document.getElementById("event").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("message");
});
```